# Cambiar el valor option selected predeterminado en django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Este select en un foreignKey a nivel de modelo en django, como se puede ver, el primer `option` del `select` en su propiedad `text` tiene predeterminado: `.........` y en su propiedad siempre viene vacio lo cual es correcto; quisiera cambiar este valor de texto en la parte de `forms.py`, intenté agregando estos atributos como **placeholder**

```
widgets = {
  'type_medical_consultation': forms.Select(attrs={
    'class': 'form-control',
    "placeholder":"Tipo de consulta que busca"
  }),
}
```

y no tengo claro de cómo poder modificar el texto(`.....`) del primer option del select que me renderiza django.
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RESULTADO ESPERADO DEL SELECT

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que estés usando un ModelChoiceField en tu formulario tiene un atributo que se llama: empty_label el cual te permite hacer exactamente eso que buscas, aquí un ejemplo simple:

```
type_medical_consultation = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    empty_label=_("Seleccione tipo de consulta"),
    queryset=TuModelo.objects.all(),
    error_messages={
        "required": "Opción requerida",
        "invalid_choice": "El tipo de consulta que seleccionó no es válido",
    },
)
```

Si te fue util mi respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada para futuras referencias.